# Trouble: 'PrincipalViewController' does not have a member named 'revealViewController' in swift

Tags: swift, sidebar, menubar

I am working on a creating a sidebar menu using SWRevealViewController in Swift. Trouble is I get the following error: 'PrincipalViewController' does not have a member named 'revealViewController'

The code I am working on is:

```
class PrincipalViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This is the line with the error
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {

        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        // Uncomment to change the width of menu
        //self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `self.revealViewController()`?

Comment: I think is the view controller for the side bar. But I did a search in the demo app that is working and there is no reference to that view

Comment: This is the site where I downloaded the code (http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

Comment: So why are you using () after the property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the problem. There is son objective-c code in the app, and the bridging header was not well configured. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

As of Cocoapods >0.36, if you're using Cocoapods to add `SWRevealViewController` to your project, don't mess with the bridging header. Just uncomment `use_frameworks!` in your `Podfile`. Then `import SWRevealViewController` into your `ViewController.swift` file. [Here's a great article that explains it](http://www.innerexception.com/2015/05/cocoapods-useframeworks-means-bridging.html).

Answer (score 2):

To clear this up for others who do not understand the answer's explanation... Make sure the Bridging header file is connected to the Path of the Objective C Bridging Header which is found in the Swift Compiler found in Build Settings of your project...

Here is a link for the way to check if it is there, look under adding it manually for a picture as well...

http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/